# USB 3.0 slow write Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: usb, kernel, 15.10, transfer

I have a Gateway NE512 with USB 3.0, in Windows reading speed in my Kingston DTR3.0G2 32GB is approximately 50-70 MB/S, and reading 120-140MB.

In Ubuntu with kernel 4.2.0-27-generic this is the speed at port 3.0 with the same device (read: 23.8MB/s write: 76.4MB/s)

Speed Test USB 3.0 Gateway NE512 image:

[image]

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0951:16a2 Kingston Technology 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb -t output:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?